# ag-Grid/Reactjs - How to get cell value in columnDefs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

I am using ag-Grid table in a Reactjs app, a snippet of my code can be seen below:

```
const columnsDef = [
  .
  .
  {
    headerName: 'Side',
    field: UI_FIELDS.SIDE,
    width: 70,
    cellRenderer: sideRenderer,
    cellRendererParams: {
      value: "BUY"
    }
  },
  .
  .
]

function sideRenderer(params) {
  const value = _.get(params, 'value') || '';
  const styleSuffix = _.isEmpty(value) ? 'default' : value.toLowerCase();

  return `<span class="side-renderer side-renderer-${styleSuffix}">${value}</span>`;
}
```

I have hardcoded `value: "BUY"` in my `cellRendererParams` for the moment, but I want this to actually be equal to whatever is in that cell for that column, which could be either `BUY` or `SELL`.

This value affects what css is applied to the text, a `BUY` value will be coloured Green and a `Sell` value will be colour Red.

How do I set `value` to be equal to the actual text in the cell and not be hard coded like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks 'A Ghanima' for mentioning to use `params.value`, this helped me come up with the following solution which works

```
{
  headerName: 'Side',
  field: UI_FIELDS.SIDE,
  width: 70,
  cellRenderer: sideRenderer,
  cellRendererParams: (params) => { value: params.value }
}
```

Comment: I think it should be `cellRendererParams: (params) => ({ value: params.value })`

Answer (score 1):

You can do something  like this

```
const columnsDef = [
  {
    headerName: 'Side',
    field: UI_FIELDS.SIDE,
    width: 70,
    cellRenderer: (params) => params.value.toLowerCase() === 'buy' ? `<span class="side-renderer side-renderer-buy">${params.value}</span>`  : `<span class="side-renderer side-renderer-sell">${params.value}</span>
  }
]
```

I guess  this  is what you want? If not please explain in more details what  you need.

Edit: You do not  really need to pass the cell renders  params, you can get the cell's value using params.value

Comment: I'm not sure what this is doing, `value` won't be empty, it will be either "BUY" or "SELL", and I need to grab this value from each cell in this column

Comment: Check the  updated answer, the first html will be rendered if the value is buy otherwise the second  html will be rendered.

Comment: Ah thank you, the renderer already handles this by adding the words buy or sell as a css suffix, but your `params.value` comment helped me to come up with the solution which I will post now